# redirect in angular-4 from app.component to login page?

Tags: angular

app component have just image... from there i have to redirect to login page without clicking anything. can anyone explain me how it happens?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 }) 
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'app';

}/// app.component.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  LoginComponent
],
imports: [
 BrowserModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { } // app.module.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@angular/router` module, define different routes (`login`, `home`, etc.). After you do that, you can use something like this in your controller: `this.router.navigate(['login']);`.

Please refer to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router) for more details.